# AppWidget: виджет не появляется на некоторых девайсах

Tags: java, android, android-widgets

Есть вопрос, связанный с нестабильным поведением приложения при создании инстанса `AppWidget` на рабочем столе.

В приложении-виджете есть конфигурационное активити. После проведения настроек инстанса виджета и нажатия кнопки *Done* я попадаю на домашний экран и ожидаю появления виджета на рабочем столе. Все проходит на отлично на *Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (GT-N7100)* с *Android 4.4.2*, но на *Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (SM-N900)* с *Android 5.0* виджет на экране не появляется, хотя *фантомный виджет присутствует и регулярно обновляется в `onUpdate` провайдера.

Также проверял виджет на эмуляторах с Android 4.3 и 5.0, и проблем с отображением виджета не было.

Один из вариантов окончания конфигурации и запуска виджета я приведу ниже, он самый стандартный:

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    updateWidgets();
    finishConfigurations();
}

private void updateWidgets() {
    IntentCarrier.updateWidgets(this);
}

private void finishConfigurations() {
    if (!isUpdate) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    }
    finish();
}
```

и да, в манифесте у меня стоит условие

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

чтобы приложение ставилось во внутреннюю область.

Может кто что подскажет, где и что искать? Удивляет, что работает частично, было бы лучше, если бы валилось все сразу и бесповоротно))